# Sending data from service file to component

Tags: javascript, angular, setinterval

I'm working on a movie chat and I would like to add timestamps (# minutes ago) on my messages. I heard that it's a bad idea to have heavy functions in your component file, so I wanted to move it to a service file.

Now, I would like to return data from the startTimeCalculations function in the service file to my component every 60 seconds, but I don't know how to do this? Can anyone help me?

**Component file: Here I connect to the function on the line `this.messages[index].minutesAgo = this.movieChatService.startTimeCalculations(index);` The goal is to change the minutesAgo property, but I don't know how to receive data back from the function in the service file**

```
ngOnInit(){
        this.fullName = localStorage.getItem('fullName');
        this.url = 'ws://localhost:3185';
        this.movieChatService.createObservableSocket(this.url)
            .subscribe(obj => {
                let index = this.messages.length;
                this.messages.push(obj);
                this.movieChatElem.scrollTop = this.movieChatElem.scrollHeight - this.movieChatElem.clientHeight;
                this.messages[index].minutesAgo = this.movieChatService.startTimeCalculations()
                },
                err => console.log(err),
                () => console.log('The observable stream, is complete'));
    }
```

**service file code: I would like this code to send back data to the component file**

```
startTimeCalculations(index){
        setInterval(() => {
            // here I would like to send data back to the component every minute
        }, 60000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `Observable.interval`

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/interval.html

Basically in your `startTimeCalculation()` you call Obervable.interval, pass in the time you want (in your case 60,000) and when you subscribe to it in your component, it will listen to a value received every minute.

`Component.ts`

```
this.service.startTimeCalculation().subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data) // will be called every minute.
})
```

Edit for implementation:

```
startTimeCalculation() {
        return Observable.interval(60000)
            .switchMap(() => {
               return //your data here....
    }
```

Comment: How do you add the value on the service side to it though?

Comment: If I understand it correctly It only emits numbers right?

Comment: Yep. I edited the answer for better explanation. You could also see other solutions, such as using Observable.timer().